# How to assign dict value - "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, error-handling, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

UserData from token comes in below format:

```
name:"TestUser1"
preferrred_username:"Test1"
ver:"2.0"
role: "modify"
```

For certain users, token does not return 'role' - like below (I want to assign role for these users as "read" thru code) :

```
name:"TestUser2"
preferrred_username:"Test2"
ver:"2.0"
```

When I use below code in my component, I am able to get 'role' value as "modify" for first user.

```
let userRole = this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims.role
disabled={(userRole == "modify") ? false : true} //I disable fields based on user role.
```

For second user, it throws error saying "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')".
I understand it returns error as there is no role for second user. How can I handle that error.

If role returns empty string, I can check and assign userRole as "read".

```
if (this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims.role == "")
{
    let userRole == "read"
}
```

But token does not return 'role' claim itself. Any suggestion on how to handle this and assign userRole as "read". Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const userRole = this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims?.role || ‘read’
```

This must do the trick. Now userRole will have a value when you get one from token. And if its not coming in token it’ll default back to ‘read’

If your role is a list, you may try out this

```js
const data = {role: ['read', 'bla','bla','bla']} 
const result = data?.role.find(item => item.toLowerCase() === 'modify') || 'read'
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you. But throws error if I use role[0] (which is my actual requirement) like "this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims?.role[0] || ‘read’’. Any suggestion?

Comment: So you mean to say your role object could be a list? Like role: ['read', 'modify'] ??

Comment: If you can provide a dummy schema of how the object looks like, i would be in a better position to help you out here! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a list. Like role: ['modify', 'somEthingelse']. But I always want only the first value of list. So this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims.role[0] returns what is required. But this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims?.role[0] || ‘read’ does not work

Comment: Updated the answer.Please have a look at it now.

Comment: Thank you. But my code sometimes returns role as a list. sometimes does not return role at all (as suggested above in my explanation for TestUser2). So I get  "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')" error, when I use the suggested code.

Comment: const result = data?.(role || []).find(item => item.toLowerCase() === 'modify') || 'read'

Comment: That should resolve your error

Comment: const roleFromObject = data?.role;
const role = roleFromObject && roleFromObject.length !==0 : 
        roleFromObject.find(item => item.toLowerCase() === 'modify') || 'read' : 'read';

Comment: or even this should work,  const result = (data?.role || []).find(item => item.toLowerCase() === 'modify') || 'read'

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. let roles = this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims?.role;
        if (roles && roles.length !== 0) {
            userRole = roles.find(item => item.toLowerCase() === 'modify') || 'read'
        }

Comment: Earlier i was using this: let userRole = this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims?.role || 'read'
        if (userRole === "read") {
        }
        else {
            userRole = this.props.user.account.idTokenClaims.role[0]
        }. But your code is much cleaner. Thanks again.

Comment: and what happens when your roles is undefined? what value does userRole holds then?

Comment: Nevermind, if that worked for your usecase! :)